# How to change the button text on button click in custom adapter

Tags: android, textview, android-custom-view, android-adapter, android-button

i have custom adapter for listview and i have button on that .

so i want to change the button text on button click for that particular item on position.

```
<LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"

        >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/name"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            />

    </LinearLayout>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnadd"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="ADD"/>
```

My custom adapter:

```
static class ViewHolder {
    public TextView name;
    public Button btnadd;
}

@Override
public View getView(final int position, final View convertView,
                    ViewGroup parent) {
    final ViewHolder holder;
    View v = convertView;

    if (v == null) {
        final LayoutInflater vi = (LayoutInflater) context
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        v = vi.inflate(R.layout.row_brandselected, null);
        holder = new ViewHolder();

        holder.name = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.name);


        holder.btnadd = (Button) v.findViewById(R.id.btnadd);

        v.setTag(holder);
    } else {
        holder = (ViewHolder) v.getTag();
    }

    UserName mUserNrand = values.get(position);

    holder.name.setText(mUserBrand.getName().toString());



    holder.btnadd.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            if(holder.btnadd.getText().toString() == "ADD"){

                holder.btnadd.setText("ADDED");
                notifyDataSetChanged();

            }





        }
    });

    return v;
}
```

When i am click on the button the button text is not changing for that particular item on that position.

How can i change the button text on button click for that particular item on particular position?

Comment: And if you use `((Button)v)` inside your click listener instead of `holder.btnadd`? Because the `holder.btnadd` changes, but the `v` is the correct view when you are inside the `onClick`.

Comment: I didnt get it. can you explain in details.?

Comment: Also never use `==` in comparing strings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should update your OnClick like this:
Use `.equals` to compare strings, otherwise you are comparing the objects.

Using `Button btnadd = (Button)v;` makes sure that you are using the view that is clicked on, this view is given to the `onClick` function as a parameter and is therefor always what you expect.

```
holder.btnadd.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Button btnadd = (Button)v;
        if(btnadd.getText().toString().equals("ADD") ){
            btnfollow.setText("ADDED");
            notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: .equals or .equalsignoreCase ?

Comment: It work perfect. Can you explain more about for use of ` Button btnadd = (Button)v;` ?

Comment: That depends what you want, I think equals should work here, if you do not want the check to be case sensitive you can use equalsIgnoreCase.

Comment: @depak, I edited the answer to elaborate a bit more on the `v` parameter.

Comment: Ok. thanks.Now i understand it.  I am facing problem here when i click on button then text is changes to `ADDED` but when i again click on that same button then i want to change the text again to `ADD` but i am not able to set it.

Comment: ad an `else` clause to your `onClick` method where you put `btnfollow.setText("ADD");`

Comment: oh.yeah. its my mistake. Thanks for help. :-)

Comment: @BasvanStein When i scroll down the listview then some buttons are automatically set text to `ADDED` . how is this possible?

Comment: Not sure, put some `Log` statements so you can see if the onClick gets called or if something else happens. It might be that because you are using a listView, that the `views` get reused, it is better to use a RecyclerView. See https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.html